# How to hide or disable one item in pickerInput selection of multiple items

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to develop a shinydashboard application.  As users select their dataset and variables, I provide the option to select the order, color and shape.  However, in the pickerInput I am also providing another (4th) item which is the value of the variable selected for which the order, color and shape has been assigned.  I need this 4th item/variable for further processing, such as, subsetting data.  I would like to hide this 4th item or disable the option for users of the app to select, as it is already displayed on the left.  If I disable it now, it is not available for further processing. A sample code is given below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                  .col-sm-10 {
                  width: 45% !important;
                  }
                  
                  .col-sm-2 {
                  width: 55% !important;
                  }
                  
                  "))),
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  #arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))  ##  content issue if longer than 6 characters
  arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))  ##  space issue in pickerintput label
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfn <- function(df, var1) {
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))      # create newvar
  }

  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
      bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
      tagList(
        pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                    label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                    choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                    width = "350px",
                    options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))

      )
  })

  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{

        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfn(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")

        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste0(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })

      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.  

**UPDATE:** On running the code above I get
```

the following output.
The last item displayed, under Group, is what I would like the user to not have a chance to pick.

[image: output1]

The user should still be able to pick the order, color and shape for each of the elements of treatment.

[image: output2]

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible.  On running your app, I get a `pickerInput` with two options: `NONE` and `NA`.  `NONE` is selsected by default, the UI is blank.  Selecting `NA`, I get an "undefined columns selected` error.

Comment: I have updated to show the output I get.  Perhaps all the libraries listed above should be uncommented. I may need to list a few more libraries.

Comment: @Limey, sorry I had missed two libraries.  I have added `dplyr` and `magrittr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#shapetype').on('show.bs.select', 'select[id^=linevars]', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(/\\s+/);
      if(classes.length === 2){
        var group = classes[0];
        var $ul = $(this).parent().parent();
        var selections = $ul.find('.' + group + '.selected');
        if(selections.length === 1){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      }else if(classes.length === 1){
        var group = classes[0];
        var $ul = $(this).parent().parent();
        var groupname = $ul.find('li.dropdown-header.' + group + '>span').text();
        if(groupname === 'Group'){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      }
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', 'select[id^=linevars]', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      .col-sm-10 {
                      width: 45% !important;
                      }
                      
                      .col-sm-2 {
                      width: 55% !important;
                      }
                      
                      ")),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
      ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  #arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))
  arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) {
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))      # create newvar
  }
  
  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
    bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
    tagList(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                  label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                  choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                  width = "350px",
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
    )
  })
  
  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        
        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("linevars",i),
                      label = paste0(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1,
                                     `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })
        
      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. As I stated in the previous question this javascript also works on only one `pickerInput` group. I am able to deselect all 4 items from the remaining groups. For example, if I pick treatment as group variable, I am still able to deselect all items from both Drug A and Placebo_NotDrug.  The first try it does not let me deselect.  But subsequently it does allow for other groups.  I will try to attach the image to my OP.  I am running your code with no modification.

Comment: @YBS You say : *"The first try it does not let me deselect. But subsequently it does allow for other groups."*. I didn't encounter this issue. Could you precisely describe what operations do you do ?

Comment: Laurent, when I first click on the preselected order, color and shape on any one of the groups, say Drug B for treatment, then I cannot deselect any of them. However, after this if I click on the preselected order, color, shape and Group value, I am able to deselect all of them for both Drug A and Placebo as shown in the new image I posted in my OP.  I am not able to post previous first image back as it messes up the location.

Comment: @YBS Ok, I was able to reproduce. I've just edited my post, I've changed the JS code. I think this issue has gone. Could you try? (PS: my first name is Stéphane ^^)

Comment: Sorry, when I write your full name with ampersand, @, it somehow deletes the first name and keeps only the last name. This time I put it without space between your first and last name.

Comment: @YBS No problem. More importantly, does the new code work?

Comment: You are simply amazing! This `js` solves both this problem of disabling the selection of 4th item, and the other problem of not allowing to deselect any of the first 3 items.  It allows users to choose the order, color and shape, if they don't like the default for those.  As I have 4 to 6 pickerInputs in each plot and more than 10 plots, I need to figure out how to adapt this.  Also, I have some pickerInputs only inside a observeEvent, and the selection appears only if the user decides to insert a line on the plot. Please post the same js in the other post, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve. Just remove the last group of choices called `Group` for each `pickerInput`?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                  .col-sm-10 {
                  width: 45% !important;
                  }
                  
                  .col-sm-2 {
                  width: 55% !important;
                  }
                  
                  "))),
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  #arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))  ##  content issue if longer than 6 characters
  arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))  ##  space issue in pickerintput label
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfn <- function(df, var1) {
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))      # create newvar
  }
  
  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
    bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
    tagList(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                  label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                  choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                  width = "350px",
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
      
    )
  })
  
  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        
        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfn(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        
        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste0(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })
        
      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  I was using this way.  However, when I allow users to subset data, it is possible that some or many or all of the levels may not exist in the subset data. I want to maintain the same color and shape where they do exist.  Therefore, I have to bring this 4th item as a variable from the user input side. Is there another way to identify the appropriate mygrp[i] for the associated line.vars.i at a latter stage?

Comment: I do not quite follow. The problem that non-existing combinations of factors are included in the choices does exist even if you include the fourth item `Groups`, or? Btw. Color and shape are not part of your data `d` so any combination can be choosen, or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: In the above dataframe `d`, if the user subsets the data to have race="H", then they will have one record.  Next, if the user further subsets it to sex="F", they will have zero records in the resulting dataframe.

Comment: If null data is the result of all subsetting, I print "NO DATA" in the plot tab where it would display the plot if there is data. If there is some data, the selected plot is shown with only the data available after all the subsetting. This 4th item is useful in maintaining the same color & shape, for only the available data. Order is to provide order of items displayed in the legend.  Sorry, kicked me out of my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, order, color and shape are not part of the dataframe.  Any combination can be selected by the user.  The only item coming from the dataframe is the 4th item.