# PickerInput label issue when inline is TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have a r shiny app in which users have numerous choices they need to pick prior to plotting.  In the pickerInput, the label text goes behind the choices.  The code below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))  ##  content issue if longer than 6 characters
  #arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))  ##  space issue in pickerintput label
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2))
  )
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) {
    #  Rename column of interest
    df <- df %>% rename(tempname := !!var1)
    df <- df %>% mutate(newvar = tempname)   # create newvar
    df <- df %>% rename(UQ(var1) := tempname)
  }

  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
      bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
      tagList(
        pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                    label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                    choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                    width = "350px",
                    options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))

      )
  })

  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{

        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")

        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })

      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

gives the following output:

[image: output1]

How can I expand it so that the label Plac
ebo_NotDrug is fully visible to the left of the last dropdown in the image above? Secondly, if the labels happen to have space, then the display gets messy with labels placed in random places as shown in the output below:

[image: output2]

Comment: I don't get your code working. I only see one picker Input and the choices are "NONE" or "NA". When choosing "NA" it says "column not found".

Comment: @TimTeaFan, Thank you for looking into this issue. I am not sure why you have the problem.  I am able to run the code in RStudio.  Perhaps I need to move the function within server.  I will update the code.

Comment: I’m in RStudio too. Maybe some version issue of one of the packages involved.

Comment: @TimTeaFam, I have updated the code.  Please try and let me know if you still have the problem. If you do, I would appreciate if you can post an image of what you get.  I do not get that error, even after I quit RStudio and restart a new session.

Comment: As mentioned by @TimTeaFan , Your code doesn't give any of the choices except NONE and NA. Here is the screenshot: https://ibb.co/St0B3d0

Comment: I am not sure why this code is not self-contained.  I thought it is, as it does generate the output shown above.  It is possible that I am missing some library here, and it does not show it to me when I restart the RStudio.  I will look into it.  The point is to show the label more than 7 characters, when inline=TRUE.  Also, when there is space in the labels, it tries to skip lines and displays labels in random spot - see second image from my output.

Comment: Another option would be to create a more minimal example.

Comment: I think UQ() is deprecated.  I will replace it with !!, and update the program.  That should fix it as this program is not letting you pick the group variable from a simple dataframe.  It is strange that it does not give me any errors.

Comment: I thought so too first but changing it didn’t fix it I think, but let’s try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

I found an easy way to rewrite `pickerInput` in such a way that it takes a new `ratio` argument, where you can specify the ration of the label and the actual dropdown menu for the case that `inline = TRUE`. I think this is the most convenient approach. The downside is that you can only choose numbers adding up to 12, where in your case a split up `55%` / `45%` would suffice.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

pickerInput2 <- function (inputId, label = NULL, choices, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, 
                          options = list(), choicesOpt = NULL, width = NULL, inline = FALSE, ratio = c(2,10)) 
{
  if (ratio[1] + ratio[2] != 12) stop("`ratio` has to add up 12.")
  choices <- shinyWidgets:::choicesWithNames(choices)
  selected <- restoreInput(id = inputId, default = selected)
  if (!is.null(options) && length(options) > 0) 
    names(options) <- paste("data", names(options), sep = "-")
  if (!is.null(width)) 
    options <- c(options, list(`data-width` = width))
  if (!is.null(width) && width %in% c("fit")) 
    width <- NULL
  options <- lapply(options, function(x) {
    if (identical(x, TRUE)) 
      "true"
    else if (identical(x, FALSE)) 
      "false"
    else x
  })
  maxOptGroup <- options[["data-max-options-group"]]
  selectTag <- tag("select", shinyWidgets:::dropNulls(options))
  selectTag <- tagAppendAttributes(tag = selectTag, id = inputId, 
                                   class = "selectpicker form-control")
  selectTag <- tagAppendChildren(tag = selectTag, shinyWidgets:::pickerSelectOptions(choices, 
                                                                      selected, choicesOpt, maxOptGroup))
  if (multiple) 
    selectTag$attribs$multiple <- "multiple"
  divClass <- "form-group shiny-input-container"
  labelClass <- "control-label"
  if (inline) {
    divClass <- paste(divClass, "form-horizontal")
    selectTag <- tags$div(class = paste0("col-sm-", ratio[2]), selectTag)
    labelClass <- paste(labelClass, paste0("col-sm-", ratio[1]))
  }
  pickerTag <- tags$div(class = divClass, style = if (!is.null(width)) 
    paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), if (!is.null(label)) 
      tags$label(class = labelClass, `for` = inputId, label), 
    selectTag)
  shinyWidgets:::attachShinyWidgetsDep(pickerTag, "picker")
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query",
                  titleWidth=450
  ),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))  ##  content issue if longer than 6 characters
  # arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))  ##  space issue in pickerintput label
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # people with R < 4.0 need this line to execute your code correctly
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) { # I have simplified your function
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))   # create newvar
  }
  
  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
    bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
    tagList(
      pickerInput2(inputId = 'group.var',
                  label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                  choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                  width = "350px",
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
      
    )
  })
  
  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        
        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        
        tagList(lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput2(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      ratio = c(7,5),
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        }))
        
      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**old answer**

I figured out, why your code wasn't working for some of us. You are using R >= 4.0 and therefor do not need to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when defining your data `d`. Adding this attribute will help run your code on systems with R <= 4.0.

I guess I figured out whats going on. Your `pickerInput`s have a very narrow width `275px` and you have long label names. You can either (i) set the width higher, or (ii) you need to change how `pickerInput` is splitting up the width between label and dropdown menue. Under the hood it relies on grid.less css classes `.col-sm-10` for the dropdown menue and `.col-sm-2` for its label. Here it attributes about 17% width to the label (in your case this is too small) and 83% to the dropdown menue (in your case this is too much). You could (A) rewrite the `pickerInput` function and define your own css classes and then add a custom css where those classes are defined with enough width to display properly (this is what I recommend). Or you can (B) overwrite the default values of gird.less.css with inline CSS adding `!important`. This is my approach below, just because it is the quickest way to fix this issue. However, it is not a good way, since other elements in your dashboard may rely on those css classes.

Note that I also streamlined `myfun`. It should still work as expected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query",
                  titleWidth=450
                  ),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    # custom CSS to overwrite grid.less defaults
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .col-sm-10 {
        width: 45% !important;
      }
      
      .col-sm-2 {
        width: 55% !important;
      }

    "))),
    
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))  ##  content issue if longer than 6 characters
  # arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))  ##  space issue in pickerintput label
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # people with R < 4.0 need this line to execute your code correctly
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) { # I have simplified your function
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))   # create newvar
  }
  
  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
    bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
    tagList(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                  label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                  choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                  width = "350px",
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
      
    )
  })
  
  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        
        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        
        tagList(lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        }))
        
      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you very much.  This css solution seems to address both the label width and space issue.  Appreciate your solution.  So, 17% width affected the label with space also?  Typically, user data can have `Drug A IV` or other such info.  I still have another issue with 4th item `Group=mygrp` in `choices`.  Any chance you have some time to look into it?  I would really appreciate it.  It is a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507235/how-to-hide-or-disable-one-item-in-pickerinput-selection-of-multiple-items

Comment: Thank you for streamlining `myfun` function.  I just started learning R and Shiny about six months ago.  I was trying to finish a new app to generate numerous graphs that are generally used.  As it is now in beta-testing, I am trying to resolve some of the outstanding issues. I will look into making my own pickerInput function. I am not familiar with CSS, and therefore, it might take some time.

Comment: I found an easy way to rewrite `inputPicker`, maybe this is enough for your use case.

Comment: This looks like a good option.  However, it gives me an error: `Warning in if (multiple) selectTag$attribs$multiple <- "multiple" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. I am not sure what the problem is here.  Also, it displays only 4th element.  Order, color and shape are not displayed in the dropdown list. As I am using pickerinput numerous times in each plot of my app, it will be very useful.  I always appreciate a great solution.  Awesome!