# Move answer dropbox to the right in pickerInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, pickerinput

i'd like to move my blue box to the right part of the sentence, i'm using pickerinput in Shiny app, This is my code:
o you know how can i move to the right part?, or what iput i should use to do this?

Thanks !!

```
pickerInput(inputId = "answer11_",
                                     
            label = "Additional Side A defense limit: Minimum $500,000, $1,000,000 for larger risks",
            choices = c("Yes", "Minor Deficiency", "Mayor Deficiency", "No"),
            options = list(
            style = "btn-primary"))
```

[image: This is my input now]

Comment: Inline=TRUE should work.  However, as you have very long label it will not work.  You can modify javascript to accommodate more space.  Alternately, you can use updated pickerInput2 function by @TimTeaFan here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520164/pickerinput-label-issue-when-inline-is-true/62565441#62565441

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just set `inline = TRUE`

```
# Basic usage
library("shiny")
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "A label",
    choices = c("a", "b"),
    inline = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderPrint(input$somevalue)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```