# How to ensure that in pickerInput choices at least one item is selected in each group

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have not been able to find an answer to this issue on SO.  The code below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                  .col-sm-10 {
                  width: 45% !important;
                  }

                  .col-sm-2 {
                  width: 55% !important;
                  }

                  "))),
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  #arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))
  arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) {
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))      # create newvar
  }

  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
      bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
      tagList(
        pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                    label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                    choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                    width = "350px",
                    options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
      )
  })

  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{

        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste0(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1,
                                     `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })

      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

gives the following output:

[image: output]

It gives the option for the user to pick the order, color and shape for each of the available group value in their data.  However, when users accidentally click on their selected choice again, it deselects that choice. In the image above, I have deselected order, color and shape for Drug A.  It should not allow a user to deselect any group.  My expectation is that if color has a choice of red and blue, they should be able to pick either color but not none.

@Stephane Laurent's answer works for the first element.  I am still able to deselect order, color and shape from the second element onwards in the treatment example above. Please see the output below:

output2

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. The JavaScript code prevents to deselect an option if it is the unique selected option.

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#somevalue').on('show.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var selections = $('#somevalue').val();
      if(selections.length === 1 && $(this).hasClass('selected')){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      };
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "A label",
    choices = c("a", "b"), 
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderPrint(input$somevalue)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

I see that you are using `pickerInput` with groups of options. Here is the JS code for this situation:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#groups').on('show.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(/\\s+/);
      if(classes.length === 2){
        var group = classes[0];
        var selections = $('.' + group + '.selected');
        if(selections.length === 1){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      }
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "groups",
    label = "Select one from each group below:",
    choices = list(
      Group1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
      Group2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
    ),
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res_grp")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$res_grp <- renderPrint(input$groups)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

For your case:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#shapetype').on('show.bs.select', 'select[id^=linevars]', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(/\\s+/);
      if(classes.length === 2){
        var group = classes[0];
        var selections = $('.' + group + '.selected');
        if(selections.length === 1){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      }
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      .col-sm-10 {
                      width: 45% !important;
                      }
                      
                      .col-sm-2 {
                      width: 55% !important;
                      }
                      
                      ")),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
      ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  #arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))
  arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) {
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))      # create newvar
  }
  
  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
    bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
    tagList(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                  label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                  choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                  width = "350px",
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
    )
  })
  
  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        
        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("linevars",i),
                      label = paste0(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1,
                                     `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })
        
      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, @Stephane Laurent, you got it.  It works perfectly on your example, when I define `selected choices` and `maxOptions`. However, it does not work on my example above.  Is it because my `pickerInput` is on the server side?  Also, it is inside `observeEvent` and `output$shapetype`, would that be an issue?  Lastly, I will have `n` variables `input$line.vars.i`, where `i` is `1:n` and `n` is the unique number of group variable values.

Comment: Please note that in the above example, treatment has 3 values.  For each treatment I am giving the user to select order (to display in legend), color and shape of scatter points they would like to see their plot. By default I am selecting a value for each treatment value. The users should have the option to change it but not deselect it completely in the pickerInput.  Deselection can be done when they click on the plotly output.

Comment: @YBS See my edit. Is it ok ? Note that I removed the periods in the ids `line.vars.i`, otherwise this didn't work. In general you should always avoid periods in an id.

Comment: It still does not work.  I agree, periods is not of any use to me in the IDs.  Even without periods it does not work.  I put the `js` above `ui` and `tags$head()` inside the `dashboardbody()`.  Perhaps I should put it somewhere else?

Comment: @YBS If you copy-paste my code, does it work ? For me it works.

Comment: Your adaption works perfectly.  Thank you so much.  How do I adapt this javascript to many pickerinputs? I am not familiar with javascript.  Can I just add the different output names and ids with a comma?  For example, add a second pickerinput info as  `$('#shapetype', '#shapetype2').on('show.bs.select', 'select[id^=linevars]', 'select[id^=linevars2]', function(){`?  Please note that in my app I have more than 10 different plots, and each plot with 1 to 4 pickerinputs.

Comment: @YBS I don't remember whether it is `$('#shapetype', '#shapetype2)` or `$('#shapetype,#shapetype2)`. Try both. You could also use `$('div[id^=shapetype]')`. This selects all the `div` elements whose id starts with `shapetype`.

Comment: In your javascript can we modify it so that a user cannot change the preselected 4th item?  That means users should be able to choose order, color and shape, but not the value of the treatment that comes from the dataframe.  I have asked this as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507235/how-to-hide-or-disable-one-item-in-pickerinput-selection-of-multiple-items/62573516?noredirect=1#comment110662633_62573516

Comment: @YBS I've checked again and for me the code I provided works fine for every pickerInput. Did you change something?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - do you know if there is anyway to make your solution extensible to a Shiny Markdown document? Posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062203/running-js-commands-on-a-shiny-markdown-document

Answer (score 2):

You are basically looking for a `minOptions` equivalent to `maxOptions`. Unfortunately, the underlying plugin of `pickerInput` (`bootstrap-select`) does not have this feature and it is likely that such a feature will not be implmented (see [here](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1022) and [here](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1010) for similar feature requests on GitHub).

One option would be build your own workaround via shiny. You would need to check on the server side, whether the user has chosen one option in each group, and if not, display an error message, maybe with `validate/need`. I attach a simple example below.

Another option would be to drop the `pickerInput` and use `radioGroupButtons`, but this could look a bit messy, given that you have several inputs.

**Example: check via server side and validate / need**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "PickerInput Query", titleWidth=450),
  dashboardSidebar( width = 300,
                    useShinyjs(),
                    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                  .col-sm-10 {
                  width: 45% !important;
                  }

                  .col-sm-2 {
                  width: 55% !important;
                  }

                  "))),
    textOutput("text"),
    uiOutput('groupvar'),
    uiOutput('shapetype')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sx <- c("M","F")
  #arm <- c(rep("DrugA",2),rep("DrugB",2),rep("Placebo_NotDrug",1))
  arm <- c(rep("Drug A",2),rep("Drug B",2),rep("Placebo NotDrug",1))
  d <- data.frame(
    subjectID = c(1:100),
    sex = c(rep("F",9),rep(sx,43),rep("M",5)),
    treatment = c(rep(arm,20)),
    race = c(rep("W",76),rep("B",15),rep("O",5),rep("H",1),rep("A",3)),
    baseline_result = c(rnorm(50, 4, 3), rnorm(50, 3, 3)),
    postbase_result = c(rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 4, 2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  dat <- reactive(d)
  myfun <- function(df, var1) {
    df %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(var1))      # create newvar
  }
  
  output$groupvar<-renderUI({
    bc<-colnames(dat()[sapply(dat(),class)=="character"])
    tagList(
      pickerInput(inputId = 'group.var',
                  label = 'Select group by variable. Then select order, color and shape',
                  choices = c("NONE",bc[1:length(bc)]), selected="NONE",
                  width = "350px",
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
    )
  })
  
  ###  pick order, color and shape
  observeEvent(input$group.var, {
    output$shapetype<-renderUI({
      
      req(input$group.var,dat())
      if(is.null(input$group.var)){
        return(NULL)
      }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        
        mydf <- subset(dat(), dat()[input$group.var] != "")
        mydf2 <- myfun(mydf,input$group.var)   ## create a new variable named newvar
        mygrp <- as.character(unique(mydf2$newvar))
        ngrp <- length(mygrp)
        myorder <- (1:ngrp)
        mycolor <- c("red", "blue", "green", "brown", "orange", "maroon")
        myshape <- c("circle", "triangle", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "downtriangle")
        lapply(1:ngrp, function(i){
          pickerInput(paste0("line.vars.",i),
                      label = paste0(mygrp[i], ":" ),
                      choices = list(DisplayOrder = myorder,
                                     ShapeColor = mycolor,
                                     ShapeType = myshape,
                                     Group = mygrp),  ## how do we hide or disable this 4th item
                      selected = list( i, mycolor[i], myshape[i], mygrp[i] ),
                      multiple = T,
                      inline = TRUE,
                      width = "275px" , #mywidth,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1,
                                     `style` = "btn-primary"))
          
          
        })
        
      }
    })
  }
  , ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    validate(
      need(length(input$line.vars.1) == 4,
           "Please choose one option in every category to proceed.")
    )

    paste(input$line.vars.1, collapse = ", ")
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are correct that I am looking for `minOptions`.  Checking on the server side is becoming messy and does not work as the input has 4 choices, but the number of variables is the number of unique items for the selected group variable by the user.  It could be even 21 or more as there is a vaccine with 21 serotypes.  So, I had to adjust the logic to cycle through color and shapes if there are more items than the number of choices I am giving.  Today I will check if I can use something other than `pickerInput`. Perhaps `radioGroupButtons` or `selectizeInput` might work.

Comment: I create a dataframe out of this input and pass it to a program that plots the selected plot.  color and shape of the scatter points, and order of legend is using this input.

Comment: I updated my answer with a toy example of `validate/need` for the first of your `pickerInputs`. I generate a `textOutput` as example and a message will be displayed that tells the user to select one option of each group. It is not as nice as a Javascript solution, but it is easily implemented and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

@TimTeaFan, that is a great idea.  That was my line of thinking before seeing @Stephane Laurent's excellent javascript answer.  Stephane's answer works for one group, but not multi-dimensional groups.  At least I have not been able to make it work for my app.  I have modified @TimTeaFan's answer slightly and adapted it to all `pickerInputs`. I render it with `renderUI`.  In your code `output$text` is modified as shown below. Obviously, `textOutput` should be changed to `uiOutput` in `ui`.

```
output$text <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$group.var)){
      return(NULL)
    }else if(sum(input$group.var=="NONE")==1){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      lapply(1:ngrp(), function(i){
        q1 <- paste0("line.vars.",i)
        uivar  <- expr('$'(input,!!q1))
        req(uivar)
        fval <- eval_tidy(uivar)
        if (length(fval) < 4) {
          tagList(
            p("ERROR: Please choose one option in every category to proceed.", style = "color:red")
          )
        }else{ return(NULL) }
      })
    }
  })
```

I will go with this for now, until I can get a better solution.

**update**:  @StephaneLaurent has updated the javascript to solve this problem and another problem listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507235/how-to-hide-or-disable-one-item-in-pickerinput-selection-of-multiple-items/62653067#62653067).  I will be using both these answers as I am not sure that I will be able to use `js` in all my `pickerInputs` based on how my ShinyApp has been setup.  Many many many thanks to both @StephaneLaurent and @TimTeaFan.

**Update2:** The final answer I used to solve this issue is javascript from @Stephane Laurent. For completeness I have attached it below.

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div[id^=shapetype]').on('show.bs.select', 'select[id^=linevars]', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(/\\s+/);
      if(classes.length === 2){
        var group = classes[0];
        var $ul = $(this).parent().parent();
        var selections = $ul.find('.' + group + '.selected');
        if(selections.length === 1){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      }else if(classes.length === 1){
        var group = classes[0];
        var $ul = $(this).parent().parent();
        var groupname = $ul.find('li.dropdown-header.' + group + '>span').text();
        if(groupname === 'Group'){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      }
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', 'select[id^=linevars]', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"
```

The only caveat is that all the output names should start with shapetype, and variable IDs should start with linevars or adjust the above code appropriately.  All ten plots in my shiny app work as expected.