# Running JS Commands on a Shiny Markdown Document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to implement Stephane Laurent's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62639634/9394364) to requiring a minimum number of selections for a picker input in a Shiny Markdown document but cannot figure out how to run the java script component. Can anyone tell me where I place the `js` and `tags$head...` objects to make this run correctly?

**Solution Using a Traditional Shiny App**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#somevalue').on('show.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var selections = $('#somevalue').val();
      if(selections.length === 1 && $(this).hasClass('selected')){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      };
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "A label",
    choices = c("a", "b"), 
    selected = "a",
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderPrint(input$somevalue)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Shiny Markdown Document Wrapper Doesn't Work**

````
---
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document
---

```{r echo =  F, message = F, warning = F, error = F}
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#somevalue').on('show.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var selections = $('#somevalue').val();
      if(selections.length === 1 && $(this).hasClass('selected')){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      };
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});"

tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js)))
pickerInput(
  inputId = "somevalue",
  label = "A label",
  choices = c("a", "b"), 
  selected = "a",
  multiple = TRUE
)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried, but I think you can include a JavaScript chunk:

````
```{js}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#somevalue').on('show.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').on('click', function(e){
      var selections = $('#somevalue').val();
      if(selections.length === 1 && $(this).hasClass('selected')){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      };
    });
  }).on('hide.bs.select', function(){
    $('a[role=option]').off('click');
  });
});
```
````